# Extracting integers from a HashSet<Double>

Tags: java, hashset

I have a `HashSet<Double>` from which I want to extract those elements that are integers, i.e. those elements that have all zeros after the decimal. Is there a standard way of doing this? I could do something roundabout, e.g.: given a double `x`, I can look at all the values after the decimal and see if they are all zero, but this seems convoluted.

Comment: You will have to do something roundabout, because, to the JVM, any double value is a double value, and it doesn't check to see if such a value is close-enough to an integer.

Comment: Be aware that big `double` numbers haven’t got sufficient precision for determining whether a whole number was intended.

Comment: Also you should decide on a tolerance. 2.000_000_000_000_000_4 was probably a 2 with an inaccuracy, so you will probably want to regard it as a whole number, depending on your circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can cast them into integer and equalize the casted value to the original

```
double d = 1.5;
if((int)d==d) // integer
else // not integer
```

Comment: It only works within the `int` range. I suppose that 2_147_483_649.0 (also written 2.147483649E9)  counts as an integer, yet your if condition evaluates to false.

Comment: yes. but you can do the same with BigDecimal and compare it to the `bigDecimal.toBigInteger()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
HashSet<Double> hd = new HashSet<> ();
hd.add (3.5);
hd.add (2.0);
hd.add (3.444);
hd.add (-1.0);
Set<Double> filtered = hd.stream()
                         .filter (x -> (int)(double)x == x)
                         .collect (Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println (filtered);
```

Output:

```
[2.0, -1.0]
```

You first have to cast the `Double` to `double` and then cast it to an `int`. If that `int` is equal to the original `Double`, that `Double` holds an integer value.

If you want to avoid the explicit casting, you can change

```
.filter (x -> (int)(double)x == x)
```

to

```
.filter (x -> x.intValue() == x)
```

which does the exact same thing.

Comment: "Casting" a ```Double``` to ```double```? That sounds really fishy to me; of course, it will trigger (auto-)unboxing, but the proper way to do it would be to cast the unboxed double value (```(int)x.doubleValue()```). And when we already talking about that: comparing an ``ìnt```with a ```Double``` works, because of auto-unboxing, but to do it really right, do this: ```x.intValue() == x.doubleValue()```.

Comment: @tquadrat casting Double to double is required since you cannot cast a Double directly to int. Yes, casting Double to double is equivalent to `x.doubleValue()`.  The "proper way" is a matter of opinion. I think `x.intValue() == x` looks better, and yes, it works due to auto unboxing.

Comment: – Yeah, you need to transform the ```Double``` to ```double```, but that is not "casting", that is "unboxing" … and is usually done by call the `Double::doubleValue()` method, either explicitly, or implicitly, as auto-unboxing …

Answer (score 1):

I guess you like to have a final result of Integers and not of Doubles. E.g. 7 and not 7.0.

So try this one:

```
    Set<Double> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(6.4);
    set.add(10.44);
    set.add(7.0);

    Set<Integer> filtered = set.stream()
            .filter(item -> Math.floor(item) == item)
            .map(Double::intValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    System.out.println(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Collection<Integer> filterIntegers( final HashSet<Double> doubles )
{
    final var retValue = doubles.stream()
        .filter( d -> d.doubleValue() == d.intValue() )
        .map( Double::intValue )
        .collect( Collector.toSet() );
    return retValue;
}
```

Explicitly comparing the real (double) value of `d` with its integer value seems to me as the most precise implementation of the requirement. No casting around, no math operations involved (although all these will provide the same results!).